# Why is my code not asking for user input?

Tags: c

I am working on a contiguous memory allocation program, and I am using this to continuously get user input each round, but I seem to be stuck in a infinite loop that I can't seem to figure out. It takes input once, but it doesn't prompt me a second time to do so. Any help would be amazing.

```
int main(void) {

initializeArray();

char ss[MAX_LINE];
int should_run = 1; // flag to determine when to exit program /
int i = 0;

while (should_run) {

    printf("osh>");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%[^\n]%c", ss);
    printf("input:%s\n", ss);

    i = 0;

    args[i] = strtok(ss, " ");
    while(args[i] != NULL) {
        i++;
        args[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    controller();


    if (*args[0] == 'e') {
        should_run = 0;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what did you see whne you stepped through with your debugger.

Comment: Who or what code  suggested using `scanf("%[^\n]%c", ss);`? BTW: problem is in `controller();` or `args`.

Comment: It was code provided by the professor. But my controller only does through to my switch statements, which then lead to other functions.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%c", ss);` The format scans two items, but the code only provides the address of one. This is UB (undefined behavior) right there. If you just want to skip over the newline (and any other whitespace), change that to `scanf("%[^\n] ", ss);` (note the trailing space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes to scanf will fix the error, you need to add `*`  `%*c` so that it ignores the character.

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", ss);
         or
scanf("%[^\n]", ss);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize that, the first one fired my error.